# Is it possible to display radio buttons without one being selected?

Tags: vb.net

I have two radio buttons in a group box. I don't want either of them selected, so the user is forced to make a choice. (I have code in place to ensure one has been selected before moving to the next form.)

I set the `Checked` property to `False` for both buttons, but when I run the form it still displays the top button as selected. I added to following code to the `Load` event of the form but it *STILL* shows one as selected.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   RBArchive.Checked = False
   RBCopy.Checked = False    
End Sub
```

How can I get both radio buttons to remain unselected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.NET default radio button selected inside a group box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030974/vb-net-default-radio-button-selected-inside-a-group-box)

Comment: @Turamarth Just be aware the accepted and well-voted solution to that question is not good. If you do this in the form Shown event, as it suggests, minimizing and restoring the form will raise the event and reset the checkboxes whether or not that is intended.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does the second answer from Hans Passant work correctly?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The Shown event will only fire once.

Comment: I tried moving the code from the Load event to the Shown event and it worked perfectly. Changing form size did not affect it. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the designer just set the default for each button = false. The other issue is that the Group cannot be the FIRST control on your form (tab index = 0). If the radio group is the first control, then put/place/move something else to hold the tab index 0 position.

If the grouping is the first control, then on form load the first of the group will be selected - even if all radio buttons are defaulted to false. However, if the group control is NOT the first control on the form, then you should not have to do anything other then just set the controls to false. This is for winforms, and not WPF.

In asp.net? then setting the group to -1 works rather well. So if this is WPF, then I would give setting the group control to -1 a try. In standard winforms, the group control does not spit out a index number (like it does for asp.net grouped radio buttons).

So, I tend to use this:

```
Private Function GetGroupBox(grpb As GroupBox) As Integer

    ' return seleted control - starts at 0
    For Each ctrl As RadioButton In grpb.Controls
        If ctrl.Checked Then Return ctrl.TabIndex
    Next
    Return -1       ' if none checked
 End Function
```

And above assumes that the tabindex for all radiobuttons in the group is set to 1

So, in code, if there are 5 buttons, I can go:

```
    If GetGroupBox(Me.gRadioGroupProvider) = 0 Then
        strProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    Else
        strProvider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    End If
```

So, now you get a group return value like you get in asp.net, VB6/VBA

Regardless, if all radio buttons have a default of false, and the radio group is not the first control on the form, then none should show as selected.
If this is WPF, then all bets are off.